# How can I Start 2 sh Scripts at the same time with this Launcher on Kali Linux?

Tags: bash, shell-script, kali-linux, launcher

```
[Desktop Entry] -
Version=1.0 -
Type=Application- 
Terminal=true -
Icon=/home/Kali/Desktop/studio.png- 
Exec=sh /home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/name.sh -
Name=/name.sh -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a script that calls both commands and then use that script in the `.desktop` file:

```
$ cat /home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/wrapper.sh
#!/bin/sh
/home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/name.sh &
/home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/someOtherName.sh
```

And then:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/Kali/Desktop/studio.png
Exec=/home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/wrapper
Name=wrapper.sh
```

Also, make sure all three scripts are executable (`chmod a+x script.sh`), otherwise you need to call them with `sh /path/to/script`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about `.desktop` entries.
At the `Exec` line, you want to run `name.sh` and another one.

You can write something like:

```
Exec=sh -c "/home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/name.sh; echo Running other command; echo ...and other one"
```

or

```
Exec=sh -c "/home/Kali/Desktop/scripts/name.sh & another.sh"
```

If you were talking about normal terminal, like gnome-terminal or similar you can run a command with  `&` at the end and hit enter and/or write the next command.